# Is this a correct idea of AWS s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I’ve not used s3 before but would i be correct in saying this:

- The idea is to sync files from the s3 bucket to your server.
- When you change the local filesystem after syncing (by adding a file for example), you should trigger this file to be written back to the bucket.

Thus should the server die the file system is intact.

**This is our scenario:**

Basically, we do not need a full EFS storage to share between instances as this is an overhead in setup we don't want to spend. We currently have a single ec2 and wish to dump app user uploads to the s3 bucket. It could be true that at some point the server is stopped for an extended amount of time or even deleted. When the server is spun up again, we want to retain the original images.

The app is node and currently this package is in use for s3 https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3

However, this package offers a sync dir from local -> s3 but not the other way around. Which got me wondering if my thinking for how to implement s3 is correct.

Comment: Don't "sync" with local folders at all.  Just store them in S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually decided against s3.

It is completely possible to use s3 in this manner and there is definitely only a requirement to build a simple sync tool.

However.. the s3 storage charges for transactions where a transaction is an up and down load to/ from said bucket... in other words, s3 is a very expensive option. You can instead mount efs with eb on build of your instance. I actually fail to see why anyone would choose s3.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure of what are you trying to do, but putting it simple S3 is a storage service, you use it for when you need to store a file for a long time period. As well as when you need a lot of cheap storage.

In my experience I've used generally s3 as the main storage server and also as a backup storage server. So basically the answer to your question would be you're right and also somehow you're wrong.

I would like to hear more about what you are attemping to do.

Comment: I added a scenario to the OP to clarify

Comment: Alright, I think that you might be missing something important which is operations over a bucket. I would suggest you to use the official aws package here https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk

Comment: So whenever you need it you can send a create, update or delete operation over a bucket which basically will let you handle your files as needed.

Answer (score 0):

S3 is exactly as it is named, a simple file storage service. If you are choosing to use EFS because of the overhead, you could very well use s3 as you intend. Your primary overhead with s3 will be who/what has access to the bucket and the complications of orchestrating the synchronization of the servers to the bucket.